# JSONLayout RollingFileAppender Line Separation

Tags: json, log4j2

I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly in log4j2.xml but I am just trying to get JSON output with a line difference between each logs.

I was getting:

```
{"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger"},{"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger"}
```

that is with `<JSONLayout eventEol="true" compact="true" />`

So I tried `<JSONLayout eventEol="true" compact="false" />` that gives:

```
{
"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger"
}{
"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger"},
```

What I want is:

```
{
"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger"
}
{
"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger"
},
```

I have also tried according to documentation at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout

`<JSONLayout eventEol="true" compact="false" endOfLine="\n"/>`

Can someone guide me as to what am i missing here please. Thank you.

Log4j core and api versions are 2.0.2.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in version 2.0.2, when I use a newer version like 2.11.1 it works fine with your approaach.